# Traversing directed graph breadth first with vertexes having longest paths first

Tags: jgrapht

Given a directed graph of dependencies, I want to traverse this graph from the root node level by level (that is breadth first) however taking the nodes on each level in a certain order. In my case, the order of nodes on each level must be sorted after their depth taking deepest nodes first.

Simple example:

```
A -> B
B -> C
A -> C
```

Starting at node A, I want the travseral to give me order A, B, C (and not A, C, B because B has C under it). No cycles.

Any hints much appreciated. I'm new to the excellent JGraphT library so may have overlooked some simple solution.

One way to solve this problem would be to:

1. Find all paths from root (A)
2. Sort the paths according to length  (tallest first)
3. For each path travers the nodes and put node in right place in a list.
4. The right place is determined by a linear search of list at first position where new node is not found in the list

But maybe there is already some built in algorithm, so I don't have to encode the above? :-)

Comment: Tricky question. Can you make this more precise? For instance, if there would also be the arcs A -> D and D -> C what order would you then expect? It would help if you would formalize what you want a little more precise in mathematical terms. Also, is it possible that your graph contains cycles?

Comment: Sure. If you add arcs A -> D and D->C, then the order expected is {A, B, C, D} or {A, D, B, C}. As long as a node is not listed before a node which has a dependency to it, the order is correct.

There can be no cycles.

This should be a fairly common dependency resolution problem. I want to serialize a bunch of objects (generating code) in an order that guarantees that an object being serialized does not depend on any other object that has not yet  been serialized.

Comment: Sorry, mistake: The correct orders with added node D are:
{A, B, D, C} or
{A, D, B, C}.
In other words order of B and D is irrelevant, either sequence is fine because they do not depend on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can simply use a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of your graph. In jgrapht you can accomplish this with the [TopologicalOrderIterator](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/TopologicalOrderIterator.html)

Comment: Great, exactly what I was after! TopologicalOrderIterator does the job.